# Jquery Background-image Change Just Makes Current Image Disappear

Tags: jquery, image, background

I am really new to jQuery and I am trying to make it so when you hover over a certain `<div>` (`#onefourth`) the `background-image` of `#bottomleftjunk` switches to *'junk1.png'*. The problem is when I hover over the div it just makes the current background-image disappear instead of switching it to the new background-image.

```
$('#onefourth').hover(
    function()
    {
        $('#bottomleftjunk').css("background-image", "url(junk1.png)");
    }, 
    function()
    {
        $('#bottomleftjunk').css("background-image", "url(junk1.png)");
    }
);
```

If anyone has any idea I'd really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Is *'junk1.png'* in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: Wow, I knew it would be something simple... I literally just started Jquery tonight and thought it was like css with image url's so i was going off of where the .js file was... Thank you!

Comment: I want to add that since the image is not initially loaded, it can take some time to show it (at least the first time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the background is being removed, so you can be sure of one thing: your JavaScript is working. This means it's almost definitely a file path issue. Calling `css()` in jQuery will edit the **inline** styles of the element, meaning the path has to be relative to the HTML document.

Take this structure for example:

```
root
 |-index.html
 |
 |-scripts
 |  |-javascript.js
 |  |-css.css
 |
 |-images
 |  |-junk1.jpg
 |  |-otherimages.jpg
```

The path to 'junk1.jpg', relative to the index.html, would be: `images/junk1.jpg`

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes so much more sense, I was thinking it was a path issue just didn't know what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the same image.  Please correct it and try the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#onefourth").hover(function () {
                    $('#bottomleftjunk').attr("src", "junk1.jpg");
                }, function () {
                    $('#bottomleftjunk').attr("src", "junk2.jpg");
                }
                });
            });
```

Comment: F4r-20 made me realize what I was doing wrong. I just started Jquery and Javascript tonight and didn't know the paths to the images were from the html doc I was thinking the url was coming from where the .js doc was. Thanks!